# PHP - Referencing constants in separate class

Tags: php, constants, web-deployment

I am new to php so please bear with me here.

I have created a class that holds a number of constants that need to be available globally to the app I am developing. However, I don't know how I can load or reference them from another class. Ideally, I would like to load in or reference the class with the constants as an array and then be able to loop through the constants to perform operations with them. Here is the structure of my constant class:

```
<?php
class MyConstClass {
    const CONST_1 = "blah";
    const CONST_2 = "blahblah";
    const CONST_3 = "blahblahblah";
}
?>
```

Answers greatly appreciated.

Comment: `MyConstClass::CONST_1`.... but if you want to loop through the constants, you'll either need to play with [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php), or create an array of the constants you want to loop through

Comment: Probably a shot in the dark, but have you also looked at the `define()` function of PHP? These will be available in a global scope once they are set. http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate on the array concept, but just to access the constant:

```
echo MyConstClass::CONST_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class file is `include`d then you can simply access values of constants like @AbraCadaver showed:

```php
MyConstClass::CONST_1
```

If you want an array of constant values then I'm afraid you'll have to manually define it like this:

```php
$constants = array(
    MyConstClass::CONST_1,
    MyConstClass::CONST_2,
    MyConstClass::CONST_3,
);

foreach ($constants as $constant) {
    // do something with $constant value
    // ...
}
```

Or alternatively you can use reflection to list constants in a class:

```php
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass('MyConstClass');
$constants = $reflection->getConstants();

foreach ($constants as $name => $value) {
    // do something with $constant value
    // ...
}
```

However, remember that reflection is always slow.

Comment: Looks like what you are describing in the first option is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question!